# Mechanize with NTLM giving "401 Unauthorized" in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a script to scrape data with Mechanize, but I can't authenticate properly on some intranet sites because of NTLM authentication.

This is the code:

```
require 'mechanize'

url = 'http://intranet/somesite.asp'
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.auth(url, 'my_login', 'my_password')
agent.get(url) do |page|
  puts page.title
  puts page.body
end
```

This is the error returned:

```
/home/igallina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:753:in `response_authenticate': 401 => Net::HTTPUnauthorized for http://sistemasnet/srd/Consultas/ConsultaGeral/TelaListagem.asp -- NTLM authentication failed -- available realms:  (Mechanize::UnauthorizedError)
    from /home/igallina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:302:in `fetch'
    from /home/igallina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:788:in `response_authenticate'
    from /home/igallina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:302:in `fetch'
    from /home/igallina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:788:in `response_authenticate'
    from /home/igallina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:302:in `fetch'
    from /home/igallina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize.rb:440:in `get'
    from mechanize_scrape.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

I already tried all three methods with no success:

```
add_auth
auth
basic_auth
```

and also tried to give more parameters like `realm` and `domain`, although I don't really get what `realm` is.

Answer (score 0):

Just went through mechanize issues, and realized they dropped NTLM support.